# Sum of all outputs of stacked LSTM cells - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Here you may see a standard implementation of several stacked LSTM cells in TensorFlow

```
with tf.name_scope("RNN_layers"):
    def lstm_cell():
        lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
        return lstm
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(num_layers)])

with tf.name_scope("RNN_init_state"):
    initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

with tf.name_scope("RNN_forward"):
    outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state=initial_state)
```

This is very efficient for a multitude of tasks. Fore others, however, some experts advise **to take as final output the sum of all outputs of the cells in the pile, along the `num_layers` direction, not just the output of the last cell**.

In the picture below, the requirement would be `y_t=h_t^1+h_t^2+h_t^3`

[image]

Which would be the smartest way to implement this in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `outputs` tensor that you get from [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) is the list of outputs of all cells. If you want to compute the sum of them, just call [`tf.reduce_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum) on `outputs`:

```py
n_steps = 2
n_inputs = 3
n_neurons = 5
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_steps, n_inputs])

basic_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
# outputs = [?, n_steps, n_neurons], e.g. outputs from all cells

sum = tf.reduce_sum(outputs, axis=1)
# sum = [?, n_neurons]
```

In case of `MultiRNNCell`, it will be the sum of outputs from the last layer, which is again what you generally want.

---

**Update:**

Summing up the tensors across the *hidden layers* would be more difficult because tensorflow `MultiRNNCell` reuses the same tensor for output from each cell, so the hidden layers are never exposed out of RNN.

The simplest solution is to write your own [`MultiRNNCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/MultiRNNCell) that would sum up the outputs from each layer, instead of remembering only the last one. Here's how you can do that:

```py
from tensorflow.python.util import nest

class MyMultiRNNCell(tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell):
  def call(self, inputs, state):
    cur_state_pos = 0
    cur_inp = inputs
    new_states = []
    new_outputs = []
    for i, cell in enumerate(self._cells):
      with tf.variable_scope("cell_%d" % i):
        if self._state_is_tuple:
          if not nest.is_sequence(state):
            raise ValueError("Expected state to be a tuple of length %d, but received: %s" %
                (len(self.state_size), state))
          cur_state = state[i]
        else:
          cur_state = tf.slice(state, [0, cur_state_pos], [-1, cell.state_size])
          cur_state_pos += cell.state_size
        cur_inp, new_state = cell(cur_inp, cur_state)
        new_states.append(new_state)
        new_outputs.append(cur_inp)

    new_states = (tuple(new_states) if self._state_is_tuple else
                  tf.concat(new_states, 1))
    new_outputs_sum = tf.reduce_sum(new_outputs, axis=0)

    return new_outputs_sum, new_states
```

Comment: I'm afraid my question was not clear enough, I'll edit it right away. The sum is intended to be along the `num_layers` direction, not along the `n_steps` one. I'll add a picture above

Comment: @Jjm Oh, I see. I'm going to double check but I think it'd require rewriting `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`... Are you sure this sum makes sense?

Comment: I read the idea from https://danijar.com/tips-for-training-recurrent-neural-networks/ (last tip in "Network Structure"). I actually don't know whether it makes sense, but wanted to give it a try...

Comment: @Jim please see an update, I think I've a way to do that